# Passing model class as a generic type parameter

Tags: c#

I have a skeleton code like this. I want to create a method that can take a generic model as its argument. Inside GenericMethod, if I wanted to access the property of models, how do I actually configure the method?

```
public class ModelA
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public async Task<int> ProcessA()
    {
        await GenericMethod(ModelA modelA);
    }

    public async Task<int> ProcessB()
    {
        await GenericMethod(ModelB modelB);
    }

    public async Task<int> GenericMethod<T>(T model) where T : something?
    {
        // Get model name here like this
         model.Name
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Adding `Property1` and `Property2` changes things a bit. Do they have to have different names? Is the fact that they have the same type just a coincidence? Does `GenericMethod` need to access them, as well, or just `Name`?

Comment: ModelA and ModelB can have few common properties, but can also have completely different properties either. Based on the answers I received below, it would make sense to make a common interface for all the shared properties. Because the GenericMethod only cares about those shared properties.

Comment: @SaraMannings: yes exactly

Answer (score 3):

I would use a common interface for this, for example `IHaveName`:

```
public interface IHaveName
{
    string Name { get;set; }
}


public class ModelA: IHaveName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB: IHaveName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can make a constraint on it:

```
public async Task<int> GenericMethod<T>(T model) where T : IHaveName
{
    // Get model name here like this
     model.Name
}
```

Interfaces are better than classes here since you can implement multiple and they have other advantages(for example unit tests, IoC etc.).

Answer (score 1):

inherit ModelA and ModelB from a common parent having the field Name, and make like

```
public async Task<int> GenericMethod<T>(T model) where T : IModelParent
```

Comment: Or maybe better - introduce an interface `IHaveName`/`INamed` with `Name` property declared.

Comment: @GuruStron yes you are right, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make a parent class for your models and pass its type as an argument.

```
abstract class ModelParent
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ModelA : ModelParent
{
    public override string Name { get => base.Name; set => base.Name = value; }
}

public class ModelB : ModelParent
{
    public override string Name { get => base.Name; set => base.Name = value; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public async Task<int> ProcessA()
    {
        await GenericMethod(ModelA modelA);
    }

    public async Task<int> ProcessB()
    {
        await GenericMethod(ModelB modelB);
    }

    public async Task<int> GenericMethod<T>(T model) where T : ModelParent
    {
        // Get model name here like this
        model.Name
    }
}
```

Assuming that you do not need/want any instances of `Parent` class, you might want to make it an abstract.

Some links

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm

to read: